# changing tintColor makes backbutton disappear

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I am trying to modify navigationBar's appearence by setting it's tinkColor & barTintColor

start up with doc on page https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/UINavigationBar?language=objc

I tried to modify the navbar on the [viewDidLoad] hook of my ViewController as follows

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
UIColor *barColor = [UIColor ColorA];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = barColor;


UIColor *backButtonColor = [UIColor ColorB];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = backButtonColor;
```

But then the back button then disappeared and the change of barTintColor dosen't seem to be effective

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Weird behavior.

1. check please title of previous viewcontroller
2. check please if there is something like(hiding back button somewhere):

   ```
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = []
   self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
   ```
3. double check color for backButtonColor(be sure that barColor != backButtonColor). Try some native color: [UIColor red]